# How can I change a set of files Permsissions from Root to user

Tags: permissions, files, directory, chmod

I copied a set of BlueJ files from `/usr/share/doc/BlueJ` to a `~/BlueJ` directory however the files in folders are set to root permission and read only I need to be able to read/write them.

So in BlueJ folder there are sub folders for each project for example 'shapes' folder.

I found this command here for changing a singular file [File Permissions Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions#chmod_with_sudo)

```
user@host:/home/user$ sudo chmod o+x /usr/local/bin/somefile
```

But how can I change the folder permissions and subsequently all files in folders for every project folder in `~/BlueJ`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
sudo chmod -R o+rwx ~/BlueJ
```

or

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ~/Bluej
```

where `-R` is for recursive and `o+rwx` is for others to have read/write and execute permissions.

If you want to take ownership of the folder and files:

```
sudo chown -R USERNAME.USERNAME ~/Bluej
```

where USERNAME is your Ubuntu username.

Comment: I strongly suggest you chown them (the final example) rather than set them world writeable.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the chown example and it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy! 
You can either do it the way Sagar said, or you could do it from the GUI. 
 Open a terminal

```
sudo nautilus
```

Navigate to the folder/file you want to change the permissions of, then right click on it and select "Properties".
Once in the properties menu, go to the "Permissions" tab, and adjust your permissions!

And by the way, in the permissions tab, there is an option to apply the options you selected to all files inside that folder, hope it hepled!